# Order Attributes for HeirarchicalRequirement's in RallyDev API v2.0

Tags: web-services, api, rally

Using a TypeDefinition Query:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/typedefinition/?fetch=ObjectID&pagesize=100&pretty=true

I can grab the Object ID for Hierarchical Requirements definition.

Using that ID I can get all the attributes (inputs) for Hierarchical Requirement's (User Stories).

[https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TypeDefinition/[DefObjectID]/Attributes?pagesize=100&order=ObjectID&pretty=true](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TypeDefinition/%5bDefObjectID%5d/Attributes?pagesize=100&order=ObjectID&pretty=true)

However I wondering how I can order this list in the order it is displayed in the "Create User Story" screen in RallyDev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this- there is no "category" field with which to group the fields.  Those editors are manually configured to logically group fields together.  You could fairly easily group some of them together based on whether they are required or custom, but other than that you'll have to manually arrange them...

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I'll just order the standard ones, and toss all the custom ones at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "Create User Story" screen.  The default view for "Plan -> User Stories" shows in Rank order.  If that's what you are looking for then the order would just be:

```
order=Rank
```

Comment: The screen used for creating User Stories in RallyDev. All the input fields (attributes) are order like: ID, Name, Tags, Description,  Attachments, Owner, Project, Etc..

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to order the columns as opposed to the rows...well you can specify which columns specifically with the 'fetch' parameter, but I'm not sure that will change the order of the columns returned...